# Error on adding android module dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

getting this error after  gradle build:

> RuntimeException: Could not read Manifest data: Activity name cannot
>   be empty.

Took help from here:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

http://marker.to/Ltdy79

But i have my activity name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.librarypro">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have not specified a name for one of your activities in the `androidmanifest.xml`. Enter a name and you should be good.

Comment: my library consists of only two simple class files and my app consists of main activity which has been already mentioned in manifest.